# Modify a kinect - Reconnect the two cards

Tags: connector, cables, kinect

I’m trying to make a Kinect camera smaller. There was a problem at some point and my client expect me to put the kinect in a vertical position rather than horizontal as it is supposed to be. The problem is that if the kinect is positioned in vertical, the skeleton detection doesn't work. I’ve opened and cut a part of the kinect and figured out that if I could put one of the card in vertical position then it could fit with their display.

[image: photo1]

The thing is that this card is connected with another card via this 14 pin connector.

[image: photo 2]
[image: photo 3]

I guess it could be possible to connect these two cards via some kind of cable so my card could stand vertically but I do not know how/what exactly! First of all, is it possible? If yes what kind of cable could I use?

Comment: It's worth measuring the distance between pins and editing into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can get connectors of the right pitch / hole size (Which should be fairly easy) you can use an IDC (Insulation Displacement Connector) connector and cable (sometimes referred to as a ribbon cable). The biggest mistake people make is getting the pins and wires to align correctly (It's easy to turn the connector 180 degrees and so you no longer have a 1 to 1 pin connection) so buy 2 of each connector and twice the length of cable.

The other possible down side is interference affecting your cable. You may have to shield it. But for this small length is should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, IDC connectors is what I was looking for.